# python 2.X and 3.X character encoding difference

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, utf-8, latin1

When I type the following French character in the Python 2.X interpreter, it gives me a utf-8 byte sequence:

```
>>> x = 'é'
>>> x
'\xc3\xa9'
```

But same thing on Python 3.X results in following behavior:

```
>>> x = 'é'
>>> x
'é'
```

But it is said that default encoding for Python 3 is utf-8.
Can somebody explain this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

Your Python 2 example is a bytestring, your Python 3 is a unicode string. Prefix the Python 2 example with a `u` to get the equivalent object.

In addition, the `repr` of unicode strings in Python 3 changes to display the characters instead of the codepoints.